# $lookup and $match Mongodb golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to get document with foreign key by using $lookup and $match on MongoDB.

There is a "Jobs" collection which stores Job document. In Job document there are two field using as foreing key "creatorParent" and "Children".
CreatorParent is a foreign key for "Users" collection and Children array contains id for user's children.

When I list the whole jobs, I want to retrieve detail from "Users" collection for both CreatorParent ID and ChildrenID. I want to marshall "Job" document with ParentDetail and ChildDetail. I don't want to write a custom method for that. Is it possible to handle it with MongoDB query?

**By the way I'm beginner on MongoDB so should store needed details on Children and CreatorParent instead of storing ObjectId?**

[image: Jobs Collection]

[image: Users Collection]

Users document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58daf84877733645eaa9b44f"),
    "email" : "meto93@gmail.com",
    "password" : "vpGl+Fjnef616cRgNbCkwaFDpSI=",
    "passwordsalt" : "99397F4A9D3A499D96694547667E74595CE994D2E83345D6953EF866303E8B65",
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58daf84977733645eaa9b450"),
            "name" : "Mert",
            "age" : 5,
            "additionalinformation" : "ilk cocuk",
            "creationtime" : ISODate("2017-03-28T23:56:56.952Z"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("58daf84877733645eaa9b44f"),
            "gender" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58daf84977733645eaa9b451"),
            "name" : "Sencer",
            "age" : 7,
            "additionalinformation" : "ikinci cocuk",
            "creationtime" : ISODate("2017-03-28T23:56:56.952Z"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("58daf84877733645eaa9b44f"),
            "gender" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Job

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db0a2d77733645eaa9b453"),
    "creationtime" : ISODate("2017-03-29T01:13:17.509Z"),
    "startingtime" : ISODate("2017-04-03T13:00:00.000Z"),
    "endingtime" : ISODate("2017-04-03T17:00:00.000Z"),
    "children" : [ 
        ObjectId("58daf84977733645eaa9b450"), 
        ObjectId("58daf84977733645eaa9b451")
    ],
    "creatorparent" : ObjectId("58daf84877733645eaa9b44f"),
    "applicants" : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly. A similar solution is achievable using MongoDB 3.4's $addFields and $lookup aggregation steps.

Mongo aggregation:

```
[
    {
        $addFields: { 
            "job":"$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$children"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "users",
            "localField" : "creatorParent",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "creatorParent"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from" : "users",
            "localField" : "children",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "children"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "job": { "$first": "$job" },
            "creatorParent" : { "$first" : "$creatorParent" },
            "children": { "$addToSet": {  $arrayElemAt: [ "$children", 0 ]  } }
        }
    }
]
```

The output will look like the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58da9cb6340c630315348114"), 
"job" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58da9cb6340c630315348114"), 
    "name" : "Developer", 
    "creatorParent" : ObjectId("58da9c79340c630315348113"), 
    "children" : [
        ObjectId("58da9c6d340c630315348112"), 
        ObjectId("58da9c5f340c630315348111")
    ], 
    "hourly_rate" : 12.0, 
    "additional_information" : "other infos"
}, 
"creatorParent" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58da9c79340c630315348113"), 
        "name" : "The Boss", 
        "age" : 40.0
    }
], 
"children" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58da9c5f340c630315348111"), 
        "name" : "James", 
        "age" : 28.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58da9c6d340c630315348112"), 
        "name" : "Andrew", 
        "age" : 26.0
    }
]}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you substitute the last `$group` stage with this:

```
{
    "_id": "$_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "jobstatus": { "$first": "$jobstatus" },
    "hourlyrate": { "$first":"$hourlyrate" },
    "creatorparent" : { "$first" : "$creatorparent" },
    "children": { "$addToSet": {  $arrayElemAt: [ "$children", 0 ]  } }
}
```

Then you can achieve what you would like to, but in this `$group` stage you have to specify every field of job one-by-one with the `$first` expression.

Comment: hello there, thank you for your answer but I was looking something different, when I retrieve job from database instead of creator parent's ID, I want to get creatorParent's detail like you listed below. Like left join on SQL

Comment: I've tried your code but I couldn't retrieve child detail

Comment: children field still returns empty array :(

Comment: I replied in the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082266/mongodb-aggregation-retrieving-document-from-inside-of-document/43112085#43112085